# Serial Scripting with Putty

Tags: scripting, serial-port, putty

I'm attempting to automate a few processes that occur over serial with command line and Putty.

I've read through the putty documentation but am unsure of what the syntax of the command file should look like. The device also requires you press "enter" to begin with your command.

Ultimately, I'd like to also add in "user prompts" in the script as well if possible. Any help would be much appreciated.